# Inline edittext javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, x-editable

[image]

The example above is from http://www.strikingly.com/.

When I click the add button, image and text is added and can be edited.

I use xeditable AngularJS but I can only edit text with variable is declared, any suggest or keyword, thanks for advance.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: thanks for comment. My code `<div>
      <a href="#" editable-text="corporationPage.slogan1" onaftersave="updateCorporationPage('slogan1')"><h1 style="color:white">{{ corporationPage.slogan1 || 'empty' }}</h1></a>
             </div>` and js I have to declare slogan1 variable: `app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $log, $http) {
   $scope.corporationPage = {  
    slogan1: '@c.getSlogan1()',`